# SQLAlchemy: foreign keys to declared_attr columns

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble using the foreign_keys argument with declared_attr columns. My models look like this:

```
class BasicTable(object):
  created = db.Column(db.DateTime)
  last_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime)

  @declared_attr
  def created_by_id(cls):
    return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("app_user.id", use_alter = True, name='fk_created_by_id'))

  @declared_attr
  def created_by(cls):
    return db.relationship("AppUser", foreign_keys='{}.{}'.format(cls.__tablename__, 'created_by_id'))

  @declared_attr
  def last_modified_by_id(cls):
    return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("app_user.id", use_alter = True, name='fk_last_modified_by_id'))

  @declared_attr
  def last_modified_by(cls):
    return db.relationship("AppUser", foreign_keys='{}.{}'.format(cls.__tablename__, 'last_modified_by_id'))

class AppUser(BasicTable, db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  email = db.Column(db.String(64))
  service_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("service.id"))
```

Because there are two columns in BasicTable that reference AppUser, I was getting "ambiguous foreign keys" errors, so I tried to use the foreign_keys argument as described [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/join_conditions.html). The above gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'last_modified_by_id'
```

When I check the database, that field does exist on all the tables that use BasicTable. Is this error happening because I'm referencing a declared_attr column? [This](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#using-advanced-relationship-arguments-e-g-primaryjoin-etc) suggests so, but when I tried to use the lambda technique like this:

```
foreign_keys=lambda: cls.created_by_id
```

I get this error:

```
InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper Mapper|AppUser|app_user, expression 'BasicTable' failed to locate a name ("name 'BasicTable' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'app.models.AppUser'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

Is there a way around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class BasicTable(object):
  created = db.Column(db.DateTime)
  last_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime)

  @declared_attr
  def created_by_id(cls):
    return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("app_user.id", use_alter = True, name='fk_created_by_id'))

  @declared_attr
  def created_by(cls):
    return db.relationship('AppUser', primaryjoin='%s.created_by_id==AppUser.id' % cls.__name__, 
                           remote_side='AppUser.id')

  @declared_attr
  def last_modified_by_id(cls):
    return db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("app_user.id", use_alter = True, name='fk_last_modified_by_id'))

  @declared_attr
  def last_modified_by(cls):
    return db.relationship('AppUser', primaryjoin='%s.last_modified_by_id==AppUser.id' % cls.__name__, 
                           remote_side='AppUser.id')
```